# Investigating header and cookie flag issues

Tags: nessus

I am working on issues reported by Nessus. Most of the issue types are missing headers and cookie flags.

The tricky part here is these issues have been reported at different port numbers, for example 443, 8008 and 8080.

Can anyone please help on how to check the request and response on these port numbers or how to check whether the security headers and cookie flags are set on different port numbers?

Comment: Port numbers are just an address. It's the services running on those ports that you need to check. That also makes this not a "network security" issue. This is a service (and it looks like a web service) security issue.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. I would first look at the configuration of the services running on those ports. Why are the different port numbers a "tricky issue"?

Comment: Can you please help with it ,as in how to look at the configuration of the service ,I am new to network security pardon me if this question sounds silly to you

Comment: The question isn't silly, it just lacks any detail to help. I added an answer below based on the details you provided.

Comment: To be clear, this isn't a "network security" issue. This is entirely a "Service configuration" issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are [web](https://www.zaproxy.org/) [proxies](https://portswigger.net/burp) and [packet sniffers](https://www.wireshark.org/) that allow you to inspect traffic. You send traffic to the ports then inspect the traffic.